# Avoiding heavy controller boards in a MEMS sensor circuit

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, mems

I am very new to the circuit designing and the "Internet of things" world. I am trying to put together, for simulation purposes, a system that can pull information from a mems accelerometer sensor and pass it on to a bluetooth module, which then sends it to a mobile device.

So normally the setup would be:

```
MEMS Accelerometer -> Controller Board (processing here) -> Bluetooth transmitter -> phone
```

My question is since the phone is already a device that is capable of far superior computing, is it possible to avoid the controller board, resulting in the following setup?

```
MEMS Accelerometer -> Bluetooth transmitter -> phone (processing here)
```

Again, I am very new to this field. I just need a setup that records 2D accelerations (voltage level in analog mems, duty cycles in digital mems?) in a car and sends it to a phone inside the car, which then does some processing to calculate actual acceleration and velocity calculations.

Comment: No, you can't eliminate the controller altogether, because most Bluetooth modules aren't designed to accept analog or PWM inputs directly. You need some sort of MCU in there to convert the data into a form that the Bluetooth module can accept, even if it isn't doing the higher-level processing.

Answer (score 1):

Fast IMU sensor with dedicated MCU uses most of its time to compute very complex matrix algebra, like kalman filtering,..etc. The calculations have to be done in deterministic time, since it calculates derivatives, integrals,.. a phone has an OS that isn't for realtime computing, therefore isn't suitable it can only display the result received via communication (bluetooth).